# How to read multi-object JSON string with jQuery

Tags: jquery, arrays, json

Challenge:
How to read/parse the following json:

> ```
> > {"d":"{\"NewDataSet\":{\"Table\":{\"LICENSE_PLATE\":\"PLATE
> > 1\",\"PARKING_LOCATION\":\"1001\",\"START_TIME\":\"05:05:00\"}}}"}
> ```

Tried Approaches:

```
var objNDS = jQuery.parseJSON(e.d); //where e.d is the above returned json
var objTbl = objNDS.NewDataSet.Table;
var tblARR = [];
$.each(objTbl, function (i, val) {
  tblARR.push([val.LICENSE_PLATE, val.PARKING_LOCATION, val.START_TIME]);
});
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What's the result of your "Tried Approaches" ??????

Answer (score 2):

Your `Table`, as is shown, is not a list. Using `$.each` will iterate over its key/value pairs, so you'll have:

```
i                 val
LICENSE_PLATE     PLATE1
PARKING_LOCATION  1001
START_TIME        05:05:00
```

Probably your input is wrong, and what you mean is actually:

```
...\"Table\":[{\"LICENSE_PLATE\":...}, {\"LICENSE_PLATE\":...}]...
```

If the input is correct, and `Table` is supposed to have only one value, don't use `each` and query the `objTbl` directly instead:

```
tblARR.push([objTbl.LICENSE_PLATE, objTbl.PARKING_LOCATION, objTbl.START_TIME]);
```

**Update:** if both forms can show, just test if `objTbl` is an array and, if not, wrap it (ideally your server should send this data normalized, though). Then your original code will work as it is:

```
if ( !(objTbl instanceof Array) )
    objTbs = [objTbl];
$.each(objTbl, function(i, val) {
    tblARR.push([val.LICENSE_PLATE, val.PARKING_LOCATION, val.START_TIME]);
});
```

Comment: It appears that my server returns a json for a single record in the following format: {"d":"{\"NewDataSet\":{\"Table\":{\"LICENSE_PLATE\":\"PLATE 1\",\"PARKING_LOCATION\":\"1001\",\"START_TIME\":\"05:05:00\"}}}"}.... while multiple records would return: {"d":"{\"NewDataSet\":{\"Table\":[{\"LICENSE_PLATE\":\"PLATE 1\",\"PARKING_LOCATION\":\"1001\",\"START_TIME\":\"05:05:00\"},{\"LICENSE_PLATE\":\"PLATE 2\",\"PARKING_LOCATION\":\"1002\",\"START_TIME\":\"10:10:10\"}]}}"}. Thus, what would you recommend as the best way to check for each scenario?

Comment: `objTbl instanceof Array`. Check the updated answer. Just one question: what would happen if there is no record in the returned set? You might want to guard against that scenario also.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to interpret what you're attempting to accomplish and put together a JS fiddle implementation. Note that I had to change the format of the "e" variable.

```
var e = {"d":"{\"NewDataSet\":{\"Table\":[{\"Plate\":{\"LICENSE_PLATE\":\"PLATE 1\",\"PARKING_LOCATION\":\"1001\",\"START_TIME\":\"05:05:00\"}}, {\"Plate\": {\"LICENSE_PLATE\":\"PLATE 1\",\"PARKING_LOCATION\":\"1001\",\"START_TIME\":\"05:05:00\"}}]}}"};
```

Then you loop with a regular `for` loop.

Link is:
http://jsfiddle.net/Dracorat/EFcjA/10/